# How can I use COPY in postgresql if it said that I do not have the permission to do it?

Tags: postgresql, copy, syntax-error

I'm using DBeaver for my little projet. I'm actually stuck because the "COPY" command can't work because I don't have superuser permission. Here's my code:

```
copy "TableName" FROM 'The_location_of_my_csv_file' WITH DELIMITER AS ';' csv header;
```

That resulted in the following error:

> ERROR: must be superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role
>   to COPY from a file

So I need help on how to use \copy because it has a syntax error when I run it.

By the way, I need a solution where I use the "COPY" command on DBeaver and NOT in the CMD or other terminal!

I'm sorry if it looks like a silly question btw, but I'm a newbie on postgresql.

Comment: `\copy` is implemented on the client side, for the client named "psql".  Your question comes down to "What is the equivalent of psql's `\copy`, only in DBeaver".  You should tag your question with DBeaver, since that is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this pretty late,
but it works with DBeaver as like below,

```
copy <schemaname>.<tablename> from '<s3:locationwith filename>' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxyyyyyyyy;aws_secret_access_key=1111112222223333334444455' delimiter '\t' IGNOREHEADER 1 maxerror as 1000;
```

Please do let me know incase any issues/concerns!

Answer (score 4):

`\copy` is a `psql` command. You cannot use in in DBeaver.